# PHP 7.2.25 FALSE != false?

Tags: php, swig

Can anyone explain this?  I assume I'm doing something incredibly boneheaded, and am eagerly awaiting enlightenment.

```
<?php
echo "phpversion() == " . phpversion() . "\n\n";

var_dump(FALSE);
var_dump(False);
var_dump(false);

echo "\n";
echo "(FALSE === false) == " . ((FALSE === false) ? "true" : "false") . "\n";
echo "(((bool)FALSE) === false) == " . ((((bool)FALSE) === false) ? "true" : "false") . "\n";
?>
```

I'm getting this output:

```
phpversion() == 7.2.25-1+0~20191128.32+debian8~1.gbp108445

int(0)
bool(false)
bool(false)

(FALSE === false) == false
(((bool)FALSE) === false) == true
```

The reason I *care* is, the documentation for `fopen()` says it returns `FALSE` on failure.  But, at least in this build of PHP, it's returning `false`, so my `if ($fh === FALSE)` check is failing, making me think the `fopen()` succeeded, even though it definitely failed.

My friend is running a different build (PHP 7.2.24 on Ubuntu), and there, FALSE === false.  I assume everything everywhere would explode if `FALSE != false`, so... what the heck is going on?

Comment: PHP's true/false constants are not case sensitive and always `var_dump` as `bool`. You must have defined a constant somewhere else...

Comment: That's my entire script, though!  Is it possible for that constant definition to have been done somewhere else, in some .ini file?

Comment: Incidentally, it behaves exactly the way you expect on my Ubuntu box:

`phpversion() == 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`

`bool(false)`
`bool(false)`
`bool(false)`

`(FALSE === false) == true`
`(((bool)FALSE) === false) == true`
*DERP well, imagine that formatted correctly.*

Comment: Do you have an environment variable called `FALSE` set to `0`?

Comment: Running out of ideas... what about in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump(ini_get('auto_prepend_file'));`?

Comment: You should be able to test this with `php -r "var_dump(FALSE === false);"` which correctly returns true... even when strict_types is enabled.

Answer (score 7):

I have not figured out the cause yet, but it is in one of two PHP extensions I built myself: remove them, and it works as expected:

```
phpversion() == 7.2.25-1+0~20191128.32+debian8~1.gbp108445

bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)

(FALSE === false) == true
(((bool)FALSE) === false) == true
```

I *may* add the details of how I managed to accidentally redefine **FALSE** in a PHP extension; depends on how embarrassing they are.

**EDIT:** I'm still looking at the details, but the short version is, I used SWIG to build a wrapper around `libmodbus`, and its `src/modbus.h` has:

```
#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif
```

... which is not unreasonable, but I lazily included "everything" from libmodbus rather than specifying the individual functions I wanted to expose, and I'm guessing that's how FALSE got in there.  (However, the resulting .so which gets deployed as the PHP extension doesn't seem to contain a symbol with FALSE in the name, so... I'm still looking.)

**EDIT 2:** Yeah, just having a `#define` in your SWIG .i is enough to have SWIG define it as a constant for use in PHP.  (Which makes sense.)

Incidentally, the section of the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) which *might* have steered me a little wrong (having me tell SWIG to include all of libmodbus' headers instead of specifying each function) was **"SWIG for the truly lazy."**  Look, when I see a section which looks like it was written **for me,** *that's what I'm reading.*

Comment: Good to see you got it figured out. This will make a useful reference for anyone else that runs into this.